# Pandas: filling missing values by last 3 months mean based on month column group by

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataFrame where it has date column , value column & key_id column , in that date column few months in rows got missed whichever month got missed in each key_id category that has to filled with last 3 months mean from 'Value' Column.

```
key_id  value  date
1      50.0    2021-01-01
1      54.0    2021-02-01
1      36.0    2021-04-01
1      48.5    2021-05-01
2      50.0    2021-01-01
2      54.0    2021-02-01
2      36.0    2021-03-01
2      48.5    2021-05-01

from above data in key_id(1) - date 2021-03-01 got missed & 
for key_id(2) - date 2021-04-01 got missed we have to fill this rows by avg last 
3months mean

 output
 key_id     value  date
1      50.0    2021-01-01
1      54.0    2021-02-01
#1      33.0    2021-03-01
1      36.0    2021-04-01
1      48.5    2021-05-01
2      50.0    2021-01-01
2      54.0    2021-02-01
2      36.0    2021-03-01
#2     40.0    2021-04-01
2      48.5    2021-05-01
```

Comment: Why is first filled value `33` and second `40.0` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely based on groupby keyid 1[50+54]/3=33 & keyid 2[50+54+36]/3=40.0

Comment: Isn't `(50+54)/3 = 34.666667` and `(50 + 54 + 36) / 3 = 46.666667` ?

Comment: mathematically right forgive for wrong calculcations but groupby of keyid based on months is important

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
# ensure correct type in "date" column
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], dayfirst=False)

# reindex groups
x = (
    df.groupby("key_id")
    .apply(
        lambda x: x.set_index("date").reindex(
            pd.date_range(x["date"].min(), x["date"].max(), freq="MS")
        )
    )
    .droplevel(0)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"index": "date"})
)

# fill NaN in "key_id" column
x["key_id"] = x["key_id"].ffill().astype(int)

# use groupby.rolling to compute averages
tmp = (
    x.groupby("key_id")
    .rolling(4, min_periods=1)["value"]
    .apply(lambda x: np.sum(x) / 3)
).values

# update NaNs in "value" column
x.loc[x["value"].isna(), "value"] = tmp[x["value"].isna()]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
        date  key_id      value
0 2021-01-01       1  50.000000
1 2021-02-01       1  54.000000
2 2021-03-01       1  34.666667
3 2021-04-01       1  36.000000
4 2021-05-01       1  48.500000
5 2021-01-01       2  50.000000
6 2021-02-01       2  54.000000
7 2021-03-01       2  36.000000
8 2021-04-01       2  46.666667
9 2021-05-01       2  48.500000
```